# Listening to an open port in Java

Tags: java, sockets, udp, listen

I'm trying to listen to an open port with DatagramSocket.

The problem is, it won't let me receive the packets from an already opened port.

Basically, I'm acting as a host/server on a Flash game (using p2p), and I'd like to be able to listen the UDP packets in order to get the IP addresses of the people joining my room.

The reason is, that the game doesn't manage accounts, players are identified by nickname only, which allows anyone to impersonate others.

Being in a league and having access to the players IP addresses via the league Forum, I'm trying to create a program in Java that would allow me to get the IP address of the person joining my room in order to verify if it matches an account on the Forum.

I'm able to see that kind of information with Wireshark, so I assume it's doable in Java.

Comment: So, you're trying to listen to data arriving to *another* application?

Comment: Why do you think an IP address will help?  Multiple clients behind the same NAT firewall will all look to you as if they come from the firewall's IP.  Then there's the fact that some ISPs assign dynamic IPs via DHCP and the same client can have different IPs at different times.  IP addresses are completely useless for identifying clients.

Comment: Yes Darkhogg, is that possible?

@JimGarrison Well, that's why I was talking about the Forum. Whenever I would host a room on that game, I would have my program opened which would be listening to UDP packets and verify on the Forum to see it the IP of the person joining my room is matching someone's account on the Forum, obviously you have to keep in mind it's a league, and the players have to connect to the Forum to get the informations regarding the games.

Comment: @Darkhogg Yes, is that doable ?

Comment: I don't think so, no. At least it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Darkhogg How so? I don't understand why would Wireshark be able to do so then? Also I continued my reasearches and found out some interesting Java libraries (jNetPcap and jpcap) which seem to both offer tools to capture/analyze packets

Comment: If you have enough priviledges (root) you will be able to create raw sockets to listen to network interfaces directly, but that constitutes a potential security vulnerability for the user. Be careful when asking for root permissions.

Wouldn't it be easier to impersonate the socket in a different port and just redirect all traffic to the actual game port so you get to see the traffic?

Comment: @Darkhogg I don't understand what you mean, since I'm not the creator of that game, I doubt I can redirect the packets on a different port, like I said I think I'm misunderstanding you here